# Method 'orderBy' not found in class \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelogsToMany

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have following relations:

in TransportOrder Model:

```
public function statuses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'Status',
        'transport_order_statuses',
        'transport_order_id',
        'status_id'
    );
}
```

in Status Model:

```
public function transportOrders() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'TransportOrder',
        'transport_order_statuses',
        'status_id',
        'transport_order_id'
    );
}
```

now I would like to get 1 record ordered by id DESC from pivot table, for that I am doing following:

in TransportOrder Model or TransportOrder repository:

```
public function currentStatus() {
    return $this->statuses()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
}
```

but it is giving following error:

Method 'orderBy' not found in class \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany

Comment: it is working just issue of IDE which was giving warning of such orderBy usage but actual testing shows the correct result